# Split up Array of Dates based on Month or Year

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an Array that returns a requested series of dates that I would like to break apart by either Month or Year based on a variable.

Example of current array:

```
array(4) {

[0]=> string(10) "2012-02-01"

[1]=> string(10) "2012-02-02"

[2]=> string(10) "2011-02-03"

[3]=> string(10) "2011-03-04"

[4]=> string(10) "2011-04-05"

}
```

In order to generate a google chart in "Month" or "Year" view I need to break this array apart and group together the "Years" or "Months" based on a users preference which will be in a variable.

Example of what I need returned if in "Year View"

```
array(2) {

 [0]=> Array(2) {

       [0]=> string(10) "2012-02-01"

       [1]=> string(10) "2012-02-02"

}

 [1]=> Array(3) {

       [0]=> string(10) "2011-02-03"

       [1]=> string(10) "2011-03-14"

       [2]=> string(10) "2011-04-18"

} 

}
```

Not 100% sure if that is a sound array, but I need to be able to do a "foreach" statement for each array set of dates so I can add up all the values (all I need is date for function to go get the value) and return one total value and the year which will all be the same since they are grouped and I'll just explode the year of the last array in the foreach statement.

Here is the same expected result but in "Month" view mode

```
array(3) {

 [0]=> Array(3) {

       [0]=> string(10) "2012-02-01"

       [1]=> string(10) "2012-02-02"

       [2]=> string(10) "2011-02-03"

}

 [1]=> Array(1) {



       [1]=> string(10) "2011-03-14"

} 

 [2]=> Array(1) {

       [1]=> string(10) "2011-04-18"

} 

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I just can't seem to find a solution while keeping everything intact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$years = Array();
$months = Array();
foreach($dates as $d) {
    list($y,$m) = explode("-",$d);
    $years[$y][] = $d;
    $months[$y."-".$m][] = $d;
}
$years = array_values($years);
$months = array_values($months);

var_dump($years,$months);
```

Comment: probably a really simple thing but could someone explain how this PHP is working? I’ve got a similar issue but can’t quite make sense of this solution.