# PHP array split into small arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with different months and year. I want to split by month and year

```
$array = array(
    '2013-01-01' => 3432,
    '2013-01-04' => 321,
    '2013-01-12' => 343,
    '2013-01-03' => 321,
    '2013-01-15' => 421,
    '2013-02-03' => 123,
    '2013-02-11' => 343,
    '2013-02-13' => 332,
    '2013-03-03' => 123,
    '2013-04-11' => 343,
    '2013-04-13' => 332,
    '2013-04-11' => 343,
    '2013-04-13' => 332,
    '2014-02-13' => 332,
    '2014-02-03' => 123,
    '2014-02-11' => 343,
    '2015-05-13' => 332,
    '2015-05-11' => 343,
    '2015-05-10' => 132,
    '2015-05-13' => 312
);
```

I want to split into smaller arrays like its

```
$array1 = array(
    '2013-01-01' => 3432,
    '2013-01-04' => 321,
    '2013-01-12' => 343,
    '2013-01-03' => 321,
    '2013-01-15' => 421,
);

$array2 = array(
    '2013-02-03' => 123,
    '2013-02-11' => 343,
    '2013-02-13' => 332,
);

$array3 = array(
    '2013-03-03' => 123,
);

$array4 = array(
    '2013-04-11' => 343,
    '2013-04-13' => 332,
    '2013-04-11' => 343,
    '2013-04-13' => 332,
);
```

I have spite array by month as well as year.

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Related: [Split up Array of Dates based on Month or Year](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9233122)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the year-month, and these values are the sub-arrays.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $date => $value) {
    $parts = explode('-', $date);
    $year_month = $parts[0].'-'.$parts[1];
    if (!isset($new_array[$year_month])) {
        $new_array[$year_month] = array();
    }
    $new_array[$year_month][$date] = $value;
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/zony9M)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting that I had on there is pointless as the array is being sorted below.

Then itterate through using a loop. This will produce a multi-dimensional array $datesArr which will contain $datesArr[years][months]. With this you can simply break apart the whole array or use the full indexed array.

```
 $datesArr = array();
 $curYear = null;
 $curMonth = null;
 foreach ($array as $arrKey => $arrVal){
     $thisYr = date('Y', strToTime($arrKey));
     $thisMo = date('m', strToTime($arrKey));
     if (!isset($datesArr[$thisYr])){
         $curYear = $thisYr;
         $datesArr[$thisYr] = array();
     }
     if (!isset($datesArr[$thisYr][$thisMo])){
         $curMonth = $thisMo;
         $datesArr[$thisYr][$thisMo] = array();
     }
     $datesArr[$curYear][$curMonth][$arrKey] = $arrVal;
 }
print_r($datesArr);
```

I have tested this code and it does exactly as I said lol. If you have questions hit me back!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve my problem using logic of Barmar's code in above answer. I appreciate your time and help in this regard! Thank you!